# JSP functions - How to declare long as parameter in TLD

Tags: java, jsp

I'm getting an error `WARNING: Method "pl" for function "pl" not found`, I think its because I'm not declaring the parameters right.

`<function-signature>java.lang.String pl(java.lang.Long, java.lang.String)</function-signature>`

is what I have in the TLD.  and:

`public static String pl(long num, String str)` is what I have in the .java file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe your primitive **long** will be autoboxed to **Long** in this case so it isn't finding the signature.

Comment: In other words: either define `long` instead of `java.lang.Long` in your TLD file, **or** use `Long` instead of `long` in your actual method so that it matches the TLD definition. *Edit:* ah you already got that :)